# Should I uninstall Python 3.2 when installing Python 2.7 from the Enthought Python Distribution?

Tags: python, enthought

I had already installed Python 3.2 on my development computer. It was mainly for exploring it.

Now I have to perform some "real" work, modifying then porting to C++ something in Python, but using the Enthought (EPD Free) package, that depends on Python 2.7.

Do you think I should uninstall Python 3.2, are there any possible side effects of having both installed on my machine ?

I fear any unwanted side effects ;-)

Comment: With a modicum of care (read: don't try to install them into the same directory), it's pretty straightforward to have multiple versions of Python installed on the same machine. I have multiple Python versions on pretty much all of my machines.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's no problem to have multiple Pythons on your machine. I currently have 2.5, 2.6, 2.7, 3.0, 3.1 and 3.2. Where it can get a little more complicated is if you want to have multiple installations of the same version, i.e. two different distributions based on 2.7, say. But that's not what you are doing here so you have nothing to fear.

Comment: It's especially easy if you only have one 2.x and one 3.x, because then you can just run `python3`, `pip3`, etc. without even having to worry about keeping paths straight.